# How to combine contents of two frequency tables into one frequency table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I had a question about how to combine two frequency tables into one frequency table.

So if I have 2 tables:

```
table1:

    Col1
    18
    19
    17
    19
    13
    19

table2:

    Col1
    18
    19
    12
    15
    18
```

I'd like to make a 3rd table, `table3` such that `table3$"Col2"` counts the number of times a number in `table3$"Col1"` appears in `table1$"Col1"` and such that `table3$"Col3"` counts the number of times a number in `table3$"Col1"` appears in `table2$"Col1"`

`table3$"Col1"` is a list of all elements in `table1$"Col1"` and in `table2$"Col2"`

```
table3:

    Col1   Col2   Col3
    12     0      1
    13     1      0
    15     0      1
    17     1      0
    18     1      2
    19     3      1
```

I originally tried doing this: 
`table3$"Col1"<-table(table1$"Col1",table2$"Col1")` but it doesn't work because `table1$"Col1"` and `table2$"Col1"` have different lengths:

`Error in table(table1$"Col1", table2$"Col1") : all arguments must have the same length`

Comment: if you set each data column to factors with levels common between the two data, you can then just use univariate `table` and then `cbind`

Comment: How would I do the former?

Comment: Try `lvs <- sort(unique(c(table1$Col1, table2$Col1))) ; table1$Col1 <- factor(table1$Col1, lvs) ; table2$Col1 <- factor(table2$Col1, lvs)`

Comment: ...for completeness. `lvs = sort(unique(c(table1$Col1, table2$Col1))) ;
cbind(nms=lvs, 
      t1=table(factor(table1$Col1, lvs)), 
      t2=table(factor(table2$Col1, lvs))
      )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
f <-function(x,y) sum(x %in% y)
V1 <- sort(unique(c(table1$'Col1', table2$'Col1')))
V2 <- sapply(V1,f,x = Col1)
V3 <- sapply(V1,f,x = Col2)
> data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
  V1 V2 V3
1 12  0  1
2 13  1  0
3 15  0  1
4 17  1  0
5 18  1  2
6 19  3  1
```

Comment: I changed what you had assigned to V1 to get rid of a hard-code, everything else worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `dplyr` solution.

First, I load the libraries.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Next, I count each element in both tables using `table`, then perform a full join. Missing elements in each table will appear as `NA`.

```
df <- full_join(data.frame(table(table1)), 
                data.frame(table(table2)), 
                by = c("table1" = "table2"))
```

Finally, I replace `NA`s with zeroes, rename the columns, and sort according to the first column.

```
df %<>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  rename_all(funs(paste("Col", 1:3, sep = ""))) %>% 
  arrange(Col1)

#   Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1   12    0    1
# 2   13    1    0
# 3   15    0    1
# 4   17    1    0
# 5   18    1    2
# 6   19    3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use a `tidyverse` solution. There is perhaps a base `R` approach that could work as well.

`library(tidyverse)`

```
table1 <- read.table(text = "    Col1
    18
                     19
                     17
                     19
                     13
                     19", header = TRUE)

table2 <- read.table(text = "    Col1
    18
                     19
                     12
                     15
                     18", header = TRUE)
```

First, we want to get a list of all possible options for the `Col1` column of `table3`.

```
table3 <- data.frame(Col1 = (unique(c(table1$Col1, table2$Col1))))
```

Then we use the `count` function from `dplyr` to get the number of instances of each observation in both `table1` and `table2`. Note, that `count` returns a column called `n` to represent the tally of each observation. I rename that to match the column names in your final `table3`.

```
df1 <- table1 %>% 
    count(Col1) %>% 
    rename(Col2 = n)
df2 <- table2 %>% 
    count(Col1) %>% 
    rename(Col3 = n)
```

Finally, we join all of these together with a `left_join` and then replace missing values with 0.

```
table3 <- table3 %>% 
    left_join(df1, by = "Col1") %>% 
    left_join(df2, by = "Col1") %>% 
    mutate(Col2 = ifelse(is.na(Col2), 0, Col2), 
           Col3 = ifelse(is.na(Col3), 0, Col3)) %>% 
    arrange(Col1)

> table3
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1   12    0    1
2   13    1    0
3   15    0    1
4   17    1    0
5   18    1    2
6   19    3    1
```